# Is the state covariance matrix (or estimate uncertainty) in a Kalman filter in 1D equal to the variance of the current normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, kalman-filter

I'm trying to use a Kalman-filter for some kind of anomaly detection. But I think that maybe I have misunderstood something fundamental about the filter. I'm following this "[guide](https://www.kalmanfilter.net/kalman1d.html)".

I'm using the filter in one dimension. It is my understanding that the filter estimates the mean of the state variable *x* and updates this mean whenever it is given a new measurement *z*. Moreover it gives an uncertainty *p* of the estimate and updates this whenever it is given a new measurement. So as I understand it, whenever the estimates are computed I have a model: a normal distribution with the current estimated mean as mean and the current *sqrt(p)* as standard deviation. And this normal distribution gets updated with every new measurement.

So my question is: can I directly translate the estimate uncertainty to the standard deviation like I do, or doesn't this *p* have anything to do with the standard deviation?

And if so, how come the estimate uncertainty gets smaller (or the same) in every iteration? I do mathematically understand why, but not why the filter has to behave this way. Say we have some measurements which is normally distributed with mean 7 and standard deviation 1 which suddenly change to a normal distribution with mean 7 and standard deviation 5, just like this figure:[image: simulated data]
If the estimate uncertainty can be translated to the standard deviation of the current normal distribution I would expect *p* to gradually get bigger when we get to the data with higher variance. But that is not the case: it keeps decreasing. So my only conclusion is that this *p* doesn't have anything to do with the standard deviation. Is that correct? But then what does *p* express? In this case, how can I then track the variance as well as the mean, and update it in each iteration?

Answer (score 0):

From what you say I understand you are using the filter given by the equations:
$$\alpha_{t+1} = \alpha_t + \eta_t$$
$$y_t = \alpha_t + \epsilon_t$$
with $\sigma^2_\eta$ and $\sigma^2_\epsilon$ estimated or otherwise set from previos knowledge. Now, the variances the Kalman filter produces at each step are the variances of $\alpha_t$, and these should decrease for a while and then (for a time-invariant model, with fixed $\sigma^2_\eta$ and $\sigma^2_\epsilon$) reach the steady state --become constant. Notice that this behaviour is quite independent from the behaviour of the $y_t$'s, the computed variance of the state $\alpha_t$ depends only on $\sigma^2_\eta$ and $\sigma^2_\epsilon$. In fact, it can be pre-computed (and sometimes is) before seeing a single observation.

That said, if your $y_t$'s behave like in the graph you show, you probably would want to introduce a regime change at time around 100 (incresing the value of either or both variances $\sigma^2_\eta$ and $\sigma^2_\epsilon$) and *then* yes, the variance of the state could increase until you reach the new steady state or a new change of regime.

For estimating both the mean and variance in your case, may be a rolling-window approach would work.